# Typescript does not detect condition in callback - Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, callback, vuex

In my Vuex store's state, I have a `foo` object that can possibly be `null`.
So, before accessing one of its property (`id` for example), I have to check that `this.$store.state.foo` is not null.

It works well all the time, but it seems that TypeScript does not detect the condition in an axios callback:

```js
private join(): void {
    if (this.$store.state.foo) { // <- condition to check that `this.$store.state.foo` is not null
      this.axios.post(`/foo/${this.$tstore.state.foo.id}/join`) // <- No error here
        .then((response) => {
          // ... some code
          this.$router.push({
            name: 'bar',
            params: { id: this.$tstore.state.foo.id } // <- TS error here, foo is potentially null
          });
        })
        .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
          // ... some code
        });
    }
  }
```

I can obviously check again if `this.$store.state.foo` is not null in the callback, but it there a way to tell TypeScript to detect the upper scope condition?

Comment: It does not work because vue router expects params to be not null. And this is not the point of my question: why TypeScript does not detect the condition in the upper scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture your variable - TS assumes that the value of `foo` might have become undefined by the time the callback runs.

Check a simpler example:

```ts
class X {
  foo: string | undefined;

  print = (x: string) => console.log(x);

  private join(): void {
    if (this.foo) { 
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.print(this.foo);   // ERROR
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  private joinWithCapture(): void {
    const fooCapture = this.foo;
    if (fooCapture) { 
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.print(fooCapture); // OK
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1oDMD2GBc0IBcAnASwDsBzaAH2gFdSATAUzTKYYG4kVoAHE0vmgBeaAAoAHrgIDyAShEA%20aMAykIGEEwB0IDOUlyuPfsQBuYfE2gArDGTFzcZ%20w0Q9UxNOPwALYhDamBgKCNAeqHhM%20AAqxAC2TBi0%20GKOSu6RWdB%20AdqmgmK5gcFGkQD05dAAogBKtQDytRGoAL4ANNAAjAAMfUYRrTxDJiQWVrb2pADqxH4AwmC8%20LSETI7OrpmRqupCwYvLq9aixUFYXFle4gdLK2uh4dlRsQlJKWkKwsrIz6hnBVStyODw40Eq0AaAGkWtAOt0%20j0Blkhm0kK0gA)